# Why do I get Code ECONNREFUSED when creating a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have installed node js into my computer and installed it correctly. Whenever I try to run "npx create-react-app my-app" I end up getting this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPfKq.png)

I have already contacted the administrator and they said that there isn't anything that comes up on their end that says that I am getting blocked. I have tried changing my config settings and setting them to different ports and nothing seems to work. How do I solve this problem? Help Please.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you